# Supersized - choose different set of slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, supersized

I an using Supersized plugin for my site and would like to know if it is possible to do do the following:

1. I have 5 sets of pictures, 2 pictures in a set.
2. When page loads, play RANDOMLY one set and then stop.

Basically, i want to supersized choose different set of slides each time the page reloads.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it up myself:

```
    var setnum;
setnum = Math.floor((Math.random()*5)+1);
switch (setnum)
{
case 1:
jQuery(function($){ 
    $.supersized({
    // Functionality
        slide_interval          :   5000,       // Length between transitions
        transition              :   1,          // 0one, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
        transition_speed        :   3000,       // Speed of transition
        stop_loop               :   1,          //Pauses slideshow upon reaching the last slide.
    // Components                           
    slide_links             :   'blank',    // Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'num', 'name', 'blank')
    slides                  :   [           // Slideshow Images
        {image : 'image1.jpg'},
        {image : 'image1-2.jpg'},
                                ]

            });
    });
  break;
case 2:
jQuery(function($){ 
    $.supersized({
    // Functionality
        slide_interval          :   5000,       // Length between transitions
        transition              :   1,          // 0one, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
        transition_speed        :   3000,       // Speed of transition
        stop_loop               :   1,          //Pauses slideshow upon reaching the last slide.
    // Components                           
    slide_links             :   'blank',    // Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'num', 'name', 'blank')
    slides                  :   [           // Slideshow Images
        {image : 'image2.jpg'},
        {image : 'image2-2.jpg'},
                                ]

            });
    });
  break;
case 3:
jQuery(function($){ 
    $.supersized({
    // Functionality
        slide_interval          :   5000,       // Length between transitions
        transition              :   1,          // 0one, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
        transition_speed        :   3000,       // Speed of transition
        stop_loop               :   1,          //Pauses slideshow upon reaching the last slide.
    // Components                           
    slide_links             :   'blank',    // Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'num', 'name', 'blank')
    slides                  :   [           // Slideshow Images
        {image : 'image3.jpg'},
        {image : 'image3-2.jpg'},
                                ]

            });
    });
  break;
case 4:
jQuery(function($){ 
    $.supersized({
    // Functionality
        slide_interval          :   5000,       // Length between transitions
        transition              :   1,          // 0one, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
        transition_speed        :   3000,       // Speed of transition
        stop_loop               :   1,          //Pauses slideshow upon reaching the last slide.
    // Components                           
    slide_links             :   'blank',    // Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'num', 'name', 'blank')
    slides                  :   [           // Slideshow Images
        {image : 'image4.jpg'},
        {image : 'image4-2.jpg'},
                                ]

            });
    });
  break;
case 5:
jQuery(function($){ 
    $.supersized({
    // Functionality
        slide_interval          :   5000,       // Length between transitions
        transition              :   1,          // 0one, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
        transition_speed        :   3000,       // Speed of transition
        stop_loop               :   1,          //Pauses slideshow upon reaching the last slide.
    // Components                           
    slide_links             :   'blank',    // Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'num', 'name', 'blank')
    slides                  :   [           // Slideshow Images
        {image : 'image5.jpg'},
        {image : 'image5-2.jpg'},
                                ]

            });
    });
  break;
}
```

Comment: Normally it is good to also explain any code. Wall of code answers are not helpful. I am glad you figured out your problem, but it would be good if your answer could help other people with a similar problem as well.